# Writing to hbase 2.0 using python

Tags: python, hbase, amazon-emr

I'm currently using pybase library to write data to hbase via python. I've always been able to write to hbase 1.0 however the recent migration to hbase 2.0 is causing issues. The main error I see right now occurs when I'm trying to write to my Hbase 2.0 table.

```
    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException. Remote traceback:
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException: Is this a pre-hbase-1.0.0 or asynchbase client? Client is invoking getClosestRowBefore removed in hbase-2.0.0 replaced by reverse Scan.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.get(RSRpcServices.java:2541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:42274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:318)
```

Any help with regards to this will be greatly appreciated.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pybase didn't have updates for few years, so most probably it's not able to correctly work with HBase 2.0 which introduced some backwards-incompatible changes. I'm afraid you'll have to switch to another library, like happybase or easybase.

Comment: We want to avoid using thrift server and so decided not to go with happybase... are you familiar with any other libs that don't use thrift?

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm not aware of such libraries. Looks like there are few that use REST instead of thrift, but I'm pretty sure you wouldn't want them as well.